# How to configure xampp to send mail from localhost in Mac

Tags: magento2, smtp, xampp

I register an account in magento 2 but it seems I can't use the credential to login as per there is no password upon creating. There is a link to forgot password but the email sending is not working in my localhost.

I follow this but it seems this is for windows:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost

Anyone can help me configure the send mail from localhost, I'm using xampp in Mac

Thanks